Deserializing data uploaded by microservice A to a Hazelcast IMap in microservice B
In my project there are 2 microservices A and B.
A maintains a cache in Hazelcast whose values are a class declared in A.
Now when I try to read the values of the above cache in B I'm getting NoClassFoundException as
it's trying to load the class declared in A.
Is there any way to circumvent this?
Like reading the byte[] value from Hazelcast directly?
Or preventing Hazelcast from deserializing the byte[] by using my own deserializers?
I tried to call a protected method getInternal(Object key) using reflection since it returns the object before deserialization. But it's declared in MapProxySupport.class which is a package-private class extended by MapProxyImpl.class.
So, using below code returned a NoSuchMethodException
MapProxyImpl.class.getMethod("getInternal", Object.class);
Please let me know if there's a way to call protected methods of a superclass via reflection or any other means.
P.S: I can't declare the class in a library and use it in both the services.

It appears that you trying to reach into other gentleman's pocket. Don't do it. You need to call service A thru it's public API.

You may use JSON or any other string serialization. Then you can fully or partially reconstruct the object on Service B
